# Subquery returned more than 1 value causing query to fail

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck with this query. i want to show a field called "Executive" that must say "sin asignar" if there's no match when joining on the table 'prospectousuario', and if it exist it must say the first and the last name of the executive. But it returns the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an exp

The query is:

```
select p.IDCANCAP, 
p.CEDULA, 
p.NOMBRES, 
p.APELLIDOS, 
p.CELULAR,
p.CASA, 
p.CORREO, 
p.ESTABLECIMIENTO, 
c.DESCRIPCION,  
(select case when
p.CEDULA = pu.IDPROSPECTO and pu.IDUSUARIO = u.CEDULA 
then u.NOMBRES+' '+u.APELLIDOS else 'Sin asignar' 
end from usuario as u, PROSPECTOUSUARIO as pu) as Ejecutivo,
p.FECHA_CREAC 

from PROSPECTO p, CANALCAPTACION c 
where p.IDCANCAP = c.IDCANAL
```

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is, and you only have one subquery in your statement. What part of *Your subquery returns more than one row* isn't clear?

Comment: Your subquery may return more than one record.  Can you think of a way to limit the subquery so that it returns only a single record?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I must return all the records of the table 'prospectos' and a extra field that must say the name of the executive that is assigned.

Comment: Join to the subquery and select from the values of the join

Answer (score 0):

Boy this is a guess, based on your SQL and a lot of reading between the lines... but give it a try:

```
select p.IDCANCAP, p.CEDULA, p.NOMBRES, 
    p.APELLIDOS, p.CELULAR,p.CASA, p.CORREO, 
    p.ESTABLECIMIENTO, c.DESCRIPCION, p.FECHA_CREAC,  
    case when exists
        (Select * from PROSPECTOUSUARIO
         Where IDPROSPECTO = p.CEDULA) 
       then u.NOMBRES+' '+ u.APELLIDOS 
       else 'Sin asignar' end Ejecutivo
from PROSPECTO p 
   join CANALCAPTACION c on c.IDCANAL = p.IDCANCAP 
   join usuario u on u.CEDULA = p.CEDULA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message says, your one and only subquery

```
(select case when
p.CEDULA = pu.IDPROSPECTO and pu.IDUSUARIO = u.CEDULA 
then u.NOMBRES+' '+u.APELLIDOS else 'Sin asignar' 
end from usuario as u, PROSPECTOUSUARIO as pu)
```

returns more than 1 row, which is not allowed when used as an expression inside the `SELECT`. In fact, it appears that the `u` and `pu` tables are not joined against any other tables in any meaningful way.

To fix, you must *join* the tables. In fact, you don't even need a subquery for what you're trying to do - move all tables to the `FROM` section and join them properly, whether inner or outer. Unfortunately, I don't know which fields they should be joined on, so I can't help there without more information or wild guessing.